# print only common string between two files

Tags: shell, unix

i have two files file1

```
    file1 

    aaaaa bbbb
    bbb cccc
    dddd ee
    vvvv
    yy
```

and the file2

```
file 2
xxxx uuuuuuu
mmm rrrrrrrrrrr
bbb cccc
oo
l
```

and i need to print the common of these two file in file 3

so the result will be

```
bbb cccc
```

i tried  comm file1 file2 >file3

but it shows

```
file 2 is not in sorted order
file 1 is not in sorted order
```

and a lot of output

is that output is only the common between two files as i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you need to sort file1 first, and then sort file2 first, before you try the `comm` command.

```
sort file1 > tmp; mv tmp file1    # you may also be able to use sort -o file1 file1
sort file2 > tmp; mv tmp file2
comm -12 file1 file2> file3
```

Note there are some options for `comm -12` you need to get you result